# Brew installation errors

Tags: ruby, xcode, homebrew

I am trying to install home brew and the other tools related to Ruby.

When I run the: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

the error is : "Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode=select --install"

I have installed gcc osx and the command line developer tools from Apple Developers site.

If I try to run xcode-select --install : 
"Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch 
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch      Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information"

There is no pop up to install anything. Just the above message.

If I go into Xcode preferences, then to down load tab, Components : there is no option to select to down load the command line tools (i downloaded them from developers site)

I have been stuck for a couple of days, Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path`?

Comment: That returns: /Developer

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: I reinstalled my OS. The steps i was following at the time were outdated.